# Trigger a Miss count when button is not click android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I'm creating a simple whack a mole game using buttons,so far I only managed to get the score of the game when the button is clicked into the count.How do I register a miss count when button is not pressed?

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);

b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { public void run() {

                int x1= r1.nextInt(array.length);
                int x2= r2.nextInt(array.length);

                b1.setText(array[x1].toString()); 
                b1.setText(array[x1].toString()); 

                int rando = (int)((Math.random()) * 2000);  


                handler.postDelayed(this, rando);  //for interval...
            }
        };

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.equals(b1)){
            //Toast.makeText(Random_textviewActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            count++;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            b1.setText("");
        }
        else if (v.equals(b2)) {
            count++;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            b2.setText("");             
        }
```

Those are part of my codes,is there any way to register a count for button not being clicked?

UPDATE

---

Okay I've got a grasp of the whole idea now,but due to I'm still not very good with android programming yet,I've gotten a lot of error while trying to do what you thought me.Belows are part of the code I've gotten so far:

```
b1 = (whackamolebutton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 ((whackamolebutton) b1).setmoleactive(this);

public class whackamolebutton extends Button{

public whackamolebutton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}//it insist I must cast a method here which I'm not sure why
 //from this point onwards I got confused by the auto fix from eclipse.
public void setmoleactive(Random_textviewActivity random_textviewActivity){
    if (boolean active){
                      count++
                                    }
                else{
                     misscount++              
                    }
}
public int getScore(){
    return count;

}
```

}
Any help with the code would be greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer implementing a custom Button:

```
public class WhackAMoleButton extends Button {
  public void setMoleActive(boolean active) {
  ...
  }
  public int getScore() {
  ...
  }
}
```

The idea is to collect the total score/count from all visible "WhackAMoleButton"s and move the count logic into the WhackAMoleButton-Class. If the button changes from moleActive(true) to moleActive(false) and there was no click in the meantime, you could raise the "not being clicked"-count.

Comment: So basically instead of implementing onclicklistener,I should extend my activity to button  and using the booleon to set true or false upon button click and collecting the true and false into the getscore function?

Comment: No - i would create the mentioned "WhackAMoleButton"-Class in addition to your Activity class. Instead of using "Button"-Objects in your Activity class, you would use "WhackAMoleButton"-Objects in your Activity, where you can use the mentioned functions. I'm afraid there's no listener for "buton not being clicked", so you'll have to take this new approach.